# Is CEDET/semantic obsolete? How to analyze C code for source transformation tasks?

Tags: c, cedet, parsing, semantic

Reading through some [CEDET docs](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) I found that the author herself recommends "to use Semantic only as source of information, and perform names completion using other packages". Does this advice also hold for other tasks? I want to analyze C source and insert e.g. a doxygen documentation for a function which matches the function signature. Which package is the right one for such an attempt? Note that I need to adapt the parser as the source is some awkward embedded we-roll-our-own-syntax C code.

Comment: People these days write their own tools based on libclang.

Comment: @wasamasa there seems to exist a plethora of attempts with elisp (semantic, helm, etc.) - all of them on the way of the dodo?

Comment: Semantic is part of CEDET, so it doesn't count, Helm is a way of selecting things, not a parser. If you want to parse C++, use a production-ready compiler for it and clang happens to be that.

Comment: @wasamasa this sounds like more work than I had hoped to find.